# Is it no problem removing token in client side?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, csrf, django-csrf

I would like to check the user is login or not.
At the first time to develope this function, I supposed to use django is_authenticated value but there were many problem with structure with vue and django.
So now I use with crsftoken, The crsftoken is saved in cookie.
So when I click logout button, I detroy crsftoken in document cookie.
And after login, the crsftoken is added to cookie.
Therefore I can check whether the user login or not

But I am considering is it really OK with removing just while logout user.

Comment: The purpose of the csrf token is entirely different. Don't use it for authentication. Also, removing a stateless token client-side is probably ok for most applications, but you should understand the risks.

Comment: Thanks. I just added codes whether uere is login flag in cookie when they are loggined. Is that safe..?